# How make animation on Unity 3D from XML file?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have a GO that inside it has three Cubes (GO) where an arrow out of a cube to another.

The position information and animation comes from the XML file.
Read XML file that's OK. The difficult for me it is to animate with XML informations. I don't find a tutorial easy explaining how animation on script.

Anyone can help me?

Below an example:

```
<group name="one" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
<gameobjects>
    <gameobject name="Cube1" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
    <gameobject name="Cube2" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
    <gameobject name="Cube3" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
</gameobjects>
    <arrows>
        <arrow name="arrow1" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
        <arrow name="arrow1" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
    </arrows>
</group>

<group name="two" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
    <gameobjects>
        ...
    </gameobjects>
    <arrows>
        ...
    </arrows>
</group>

<group name="three" start="x,y,z" end="x,y,z">
    ...
</group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to use an asset called DoTween: http://dotween.demigiant.com/download.php

Once you've imported that you can animate your GameObjects like this:

```
MyObject.transform.position = startValue;
MyObject.transform.DOMove(endValue, 3f);
```

You can also chain various commands. For instance, if you want it to ease in and out (to make the animation smooth) then you can change the second line to:

```
MyObject.transform.DOMove(endValue, 3f).SetEase(Ease.InOutSine);
```

And if you wanted to run a specific method when the animation is complete then:

```
MyObject.transform.DOMove(endValue, 3f).SetEase(Ease.InOutSine).OnComplete(MyMethodToRunWhenDone);
```

There is a ton more that the library can do. Checkout the documentation here: http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I see the examples and I think that this will help me.